# How to call script on specific page with my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Super basic but I can not get it to work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "It's great.",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
      "css": ["myStyles.css"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
alert("Hello, world!");
```

I have done some reading and this does not work. I am just starting and my basic script won't run... I want it to fire on every page reload whenever I visit YouTube.

**Adding this to the JSON and having my alert inside the script did work but only when I click the extension icon in the top right corner and that is not what I want.**

```
"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
```

I copied the example right from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: I just used your exact manifest (without the myStyles.css though), and contentScript.js ... and it works fine - you do have a myStyles.css file, right? (though, not having that file doesn't seem to break anything)

Comment: I did not have the css file and adding it did nothing. So every time you refresh you get the alert on youtube.com..? Am I having to reload my script in the chrome dev console on every save?

Comment: how are you loading the webExtension?

Comment: chrome://extensions/ I just clicked `load unpacked` on my folder containing the files. Editing my popup.html file works when I make changes. Although, adding to `myStyles.css` also does nothing...

Comment: odd, because when I tried loading it with `"css"` but no css file, it wouldn't load at all because of the missing file - are you sure you're doing it right?

Comment: LOL I hit the little unlabeled 'refresh' looking icon in the console and now it works. Thanks... But it only shows the alert on a page refresh, not when clicking to new pages? And the css does not work still.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173855/discussion-between-taylor-a-leach-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: The site is using AJAX navigation so you need to dynamically detect it, see this answer that explains and links to some YouTube-specific examples: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)